# Flutter Build failure

Tags: flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

I'm unable to build an app with a build failure. The following is what is observed when the build fails with exit code 1 :

```html
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +5 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script 'E:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command 'E:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[   +1 ms] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[   +1 ms] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 23s
[ +569 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 24.0s)
[   +3 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 25,982ms.
[   +5 ms]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:699:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is my build.gradle code :

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {gradle
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

ext {
    flutterFFmpegPackage = "full-gpl-lts"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My gradle wrapper :

```html
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

Flutter doctor shows :

```html
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.708], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at E:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (4 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\earthling\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.68.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.708]
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.39
```

App level build.gradle

```html
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.earthling_app_final"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

The following has already been done :

- Replaced the flutter folder entirely by downloading flutter stable 3.0.2 and run flutter pub get.
- Deleted build folder
- Deleted pubspec.lock
- Re-Ran ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace --warning-mode all

The error still exists.

Comment: in Android studio try Invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Tried. No change

Comment: does Gradle normally work for other projects or able to simulate? Check your firewall!

Comment: First project I'm trying.

Comment: did flutter run work?

Comment: nope. it didnt.

Comment: Try downgrading your Gradle version to less than 7.

Comment: Downgrading to versions ? - gradle plugin and gradle distribution ?

Comment: Yes. Try for both. But give priority to distributionUrl in Gradle wrapper properties.

Comment: I changed it to 6.0-all and ran flutter run -v. No change

Comment: what is your jdk version?

Comment: Hi. Updated flutter doctor with details (verbose)

Comment: can update your app-level build.gradle

Comment: done.pls check.

Comment: Hello. I've updated as you asked

Comment: everything seems normal. try removing .gradle folder and flutter clean and flutter pub get and then flutter run. Its my last hope

Comment: also, try to open the android project alone in the android studio (if your android project has .iml file) and then try to run from there to get more info on the error

Comment: Hi. Btw this is the open source stack I'm using https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245537/discussion-between-prabhakaran-and-earthling).

Comment: have same issue, with exact same stack trace "throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)"... etc

Answer (score 0):

Please take a backup of your project. Run `flutter create .`. This should create all missing files. As an alternative create a new project in 3.0.2 and copy files to the new project and try building it

Comment: Did that. Restored the old backup to the newly created flutter folder with "Yes to all" replace option. Hope that's the way to go about it ?

Comment: Create a new flutter project with same package name as that of your source.  Copy assets, lib to the new project. Copy the dependencies from old pubspec to the new one. If you have any plist or json files copy that also to the new project. Edit manifest and info plist as required. Then build

Comment: Did exatly as you mentioned. Same issue. Got to do something with gradle versions ?

Comment: Where exatly i find this in VScode? Using Windows btw

Comment: its in Xcode. Not in vs code

Comment: I'm in VScode Windows

Comment: Create an empty project and build it. Does that build as expected?

Comment: Hi Kaushik. Created an empty project and it built successfully.

Comment: This is the error "The include file 'package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml' in 'e:\App Development\my_app_final\analysis_options.yaml' can't be found when analyzing 'e:\App Development\my_app_final'"

Comment: I commented out the flutter_lint include statement. The original errors still persists

Comment: please run flutter run -v and post the results here

Comment: Check the error trace which is now updated.

Comment: Hi Kaushik. Kindly check.

Comment: Copy lib, assets to the empty project, copy dependencies from pubspec yaml file and add firebase json and/or plist file edit manifest if required and run it.

Comment: If you remember, you already said this in your previous comments?